# Escape symbols in Rebol url

Tags: url, escaping, rebol, rebol2

I am using Rebol 2.7.8.3.1. I am trying to escape an `@` symbol in my url, but it is not working. I have also tried manually escaping it, but that does not work either.

I have tried the following:

```
read ftp://mydomain:12345/path/to/@folderA
read ftp://mydomain:12345/path/to/%40folderA
```

If I have a folder, `folderB` (no `@` in path), it works fine:

```
read ftp://mydomain:12345/path/to/folderB
```

I have also tried writing the url as a string, both unescaped and not, and then used `to-url`, but it gives similar results.

Using `decode-url`, it seems like Rebol misinterprets the url in all my cases.

How do I escape urls in Rebol?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this variation

```
read [
scheme: 'ftp
 host: "mydomain"
 port-id: 12345
 path: "path/to/"
 target: "@folderA"
]
```

in order to make it complete you can use

```
read [
 scheme: 'ftp
 host: "mydomain"
 port-id: 12345
 user: ask "user? "
 pass: ask/hide "password? "
 path: "path/to/"
 target: "@folderA"
]
```

Comment: I added a version showing the usage of additional port fields

Comment: This is also useful if your password includes @ chars.